# How to call alert message in login form Oracle Forms Builder?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I created login form successfully in Oracle Forms Builder 11g.

I created alert message when user enter invalid username or password.

My Code when login button is pressed:

```
DECLARE
    v_login VARCHAR2(300);  
BEGIN
    SELECT 'x' 
      INTO v_login
      FROM users
      WHERE user_name = :login.user_name
        AND password = :login.password;

    IF SQL%FOUND THEN
        OPEN_FORM ('');
    END IF; 
END;
```

How to call alert message in this code?

Comment: Shouldn't you be handling `no_data_found` exceptions for that `select into`? Are you storing plain text passwords? It might be more secure if you hashed them at least.

Comment: @William Robertson i tried with no_data_found but error show on the bottom, i want to display a error dialog message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to call the `MESSAGE` built-in twice, consecutively. Why? Because the first one displays message in the status bar, but the second one will force a pop-up window to open and is - thus - more visible.

For example:

```
declare
  v_login varchar2(1);
begin
  select max('x')   --> MAX to avoid no_data_found
    into v_login
    from users
    where user_name = :login.user_name
      and password  = :login.password;

  if v_login is null then
     message('Invalid credentials');   --> call MESSAGE twice
     message('Invalid credentials'); 
  else
     open_form('');
  end if;
end;
```

P.S. Barbaros edited my code, removing message text in the second `MESSAGE` call:

```
 message('Invalid credentials');   --> call MESSAGE twice
 message('');
```

Well, that's wrong (at least, in Forms version(s) I've used). You **have to** use the message text in both statements, otherwise it won't work as expected. Therefore, I reverted your change.